# input size getting much lower when increasing maxPartitionBytes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm tuning a spark (v2.2.3) sql job that reads from parquet (about 1TB of data). I'm reading more parquet parts into a single spark partition, by increasing `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` from default 128MB to 1280MB.
The effect is fantastic (about 30% reduction in total time across all tasks).
What I'm struggling to understand is how come the total input size is greatly reduced. 
With default 128MB, data is read into 12033 partitions, with total input of 61.9 GB. With the altered configuration, data is read into 1651, with less than half the input size - only 26.5 GB. 
No doubt this is a good outcome, but I'm just trying to understand it, at the end - the same amount of records is read, the same exact columns. 
If it matters, using all the other defaults - HDFS block size is 128MB, parquet block size (row group) is 128MB, parquet page size is 1MB.

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Didn't get an answer back then, and it's been a while, but I think I do have a good explanation for it. Our schema is quite huge (over 1k column), and each parquet part may contain multiple row groups, and a single footer for all row groups. So when using default `maxPartitionBytes`, chances that more row groups from same file are read into multiple spark partitions, each has to read the entire footer. Overall we estimate our metadata across entire dataset to be ~500GB, so that's substantial overhead.